# Call Docker API without docker daemon

Tags: docker, docker-api

I was wondering is there a way to make a call to Docker API without `docker daemon`.

I went through their docs and a little bit of source code behind Docker CLI and couldn't find an answer.

I want to make a HTTP/HTTPS call to Docker API **directly**! I don't want to install `docker` CLI. Is this somehow possible and can you give an example?

EDIT:

I want to make Docker Registry API call without having to install `docker` to test credentials, which I would later use for `docker login` command.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a little confused. You can't make a call to the Docker API *without* the Docker daemon because the API *is* the daemon (or at least, the daemon exposes the API).

You can of course make requests to (control) the API / daemon without the Docker *client* though. Simply fire your requests at the socket (unix:///var/run/docker.sock) directly. Or if you want to expose it as HTTP(S recommended) then you can do this by altering the daemon startup options and instead send request over HTTP(S) to that address.

Comment: There are also lots of libraries in different languages to wrap this interaction, for instance docker-py for python.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is that I cannot have `docker daemon` on my machine. You're saying that API is only exposed through daemon and nowhere else?

Comment: Also, I only need the `docker login` API call, can that be achieved without the  daemon somehow?

Comment: The daemon is the thing that does all the work. You need to connect to a daemon _somewhere_ for that to work.

Answer (score 0):

#### docker CLI <==[ Docker Engine API ]==> dockerd

The docker CLI communicates with a docker daemon using the Docker Engine API. The latest version is [v1.41](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/)

The CLI and daemon don't need to be on the same machine. By setting the docker context, you can direct the docker CLI to communicate with a remote docker daemon, hence without installing Docker locally. Similarly, if you issue Docker Engine API calls using `curl` or any other SDK, you may use unix:///var/run/docker.sock for the local daemon (if installed), or the URL of the remote daemon.

#### dockerd <==[ Docker Registry API ]==> Docker Registry

The docker daemon communicates with a docker registry using the Docker Registry API. The latest version is [v2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/). A `docker pull alpine` tells the daemon at the current *context* to issue a Docker Registry API call to the `https://registry-1.docker.io/v2` endpoint at DockerHub, while `docker pull registry.gitlab.com/username/image:tag` tells the daemon to issue a Docker Registry API call to the `https://registry.gitlab.com/v2` endpoint at your private GitLab container registry.